# API doesn't accept requests.put HTTP call, JSON formatting

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to make a HTTP call using the Requests HTTP library for Python.

I have this code:

```
import requests
import json

body = json.dumps({"on": "false"})
url = "http://192.168.100.100/api/0000/lights/4/state"
r = requests.put(url=url, data=body)
```

However, the API responds with

```
"error": {
            "type": 7,
            "address": "/lights/4/state/on",
            "description": "invalid value,  true }, for parameter, on"
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but it could be that the BODY is getting formatted wrong; r.request.body says

```
{"on": "false"}
```

when it should be

```
{"on": false}
```

If I take off the quotes from the code I get

```
NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

The call works when done in a browser, so I know the value is correct for this parameter. How can I correctly send this call?

Comment: The boolean false is capitalized in Python: `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `body = json.dumps({"on": "false"})` to `body = json.dumps({"on": False})`

Notice capitalization on `False` in python.

Answer (score 0):

The API might be looking for a json bool as the value for the key `on`. If that is the case then `json.dumps({"on":False})` converts the python bool `False` to json bool `false` in the string.

PS: This is also how you would convert python's `None` to json's `null` and other json specific keywords.